# Singleton sets and net criteria for closeness

Tags: general-topology

Theorem. Let $(X,U)$ be a topological space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Then

$x \in cl(A)$ if and only if there is a net in $A$ that converges to $x$.

My question?

Does this theorem imply that a singleton set, say for example $\{a\}$, is closed?

Here is what I think.

If $x \in cl(\{a\})$, then there is a net in $\{a\}$ that converges to $x$. But the only possible net here is $\{a,a,a,a,...\}$ which converges to $a$ and so $x=a$. So $cl(\{a\})=\{a\}$ and hence $\{a\}$ is closed.

Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Singletons being closed is the criterion known as $T_0$. It is not always true, for instance, in the trivial topology $U=\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Comment: But the theorem, which I got from a book, implies that.

Comment: Yes, $(a,a\ldots)$ is the only sequence in $\{a\}$, but if the topology isn't $T_0$, then limits aren't unique. There might be other points to where the same sequence converges.

Comment: I understood you now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Belatedly correcting @Arthur’s first comment: singletons being closed is equivalent to $T_1$ separation, not $T_0$ separation. The [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is $T_0$, but the singleton $\{1\}$ is not closed: $\operatorname{cl}\{1\}=\{0,1\}$, and the sequence $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ converges to both $1$ and $0$.